# How do I fold a bicycle tire?

Tags: maintenance, mountain-bike, tire

I have Race King (continental) 2.2 MTB 28" tires that I need to store until it's winter and snows again. They are foldable, and I planned to store them in their original boxes, but how do I properly fold them so they fit in the boxes like they did when they were new?

I've tried to just fold them, but they don't fit in the boxes. I need a good description of how to fold them, and pictures are welcome.

Comment: Once they've been used they cease to be easily foldable.  You can, of course, always fold it the way you [fold a non-foldable tire](http://sheldonbrown.com/video/tire-folding.html).

Comment: @DanielRHicks well I want them to fit in the little box that they came in, and when I've tried just to fold them. they just haven't fit.
So I need some guidance in folding them, please help.

Comment: Like I said, once a foldable tire has been used on a bike they cease to fold nicely.  You can try to flatten the tire again, but it won't want to go.  (You do remember how it came out of the box, right?  More of a cylinder than a torus.)

Comment: that's my problem I don't know how I should "puzzle it" into the box again. all my attempts have failed because  it was too wide and too hide. Which is strange...

Comment: Maybe you need a bigger box.

Comment: it's the original box that they came in, How did they get it in there to begin with?

Comment: The tire was smaller before you inflated it.  It stretches.

Comment: indeed, it stretches the side wall once you inflate it. never gets as flat as original state.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't figure out how to fold it back like it came, you can try a method of looping it 3 times to fold it in to a smaller size which works for non-folding tires as well.

How to fold a tire

http://home.comcast.net/~mandmlj/tirefolding/index.html

or a video version of this method from sheldon brown

http://sheldonbrown.com/video/tire-folding.html